# Nodejs (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier)

Tags: node.js

I am new to code but have used nodejs in the past with no issues.....I'm trying to create a bridge between telegram and discord chat bot.

I am excuting the exact commands in the github document but it keeps coming up with

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I can't seem to get past this issue, can someone help me?

Comment: Please include a snippet of your code.

Comment: It's not letting me add an image but here is the link [link] (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/595698018272018457/740903674582401132/unknown.png)

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/TediCross/TediCross) This is github link